# Hidden field not appearing in PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms, hidden

Okay, so i'm sending a html 5 form to a php script with some hidden field. One hidden field is working but the other isn't. Could someone help me clear things up?

Here's the form:

```
<form action="mail_action.php" method="post">
    <!--Hidden information data-->
    <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="example@googlemail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email_subject" value="Hello World" />

    <!--The form-->
    <input name="form_data[]">
    <input name="form_data[]">
    <input name="form_data[]">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

And here's the script:

```
<?php
//Grabbing hidden field data.
$email = $_POST["email_address"];
$subject = $_POST["email_subject"];
$headers = 'From: no-reply@example.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: no-reply@example.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

foreach($_POST['form_data'] as $item)
{
//Asigning the message fields to $message variable.
$message .= $item;

//The spaces inbetweeen
$message .= "\r\n";
}

if(mail ($email, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "Your Message was sucessfully emailed to: ".$email;
    } else {
        echo "Opps, Didn't send.";  
        }
?>
```

The email_address hidden field works but not the subject, future thanks.

Comment: Just a comment -- it's probably not a good idea to put the recipient address in a hidden field like that; a spammer could very easily work around that to send emails to pretty much anyone, with basically any content he wanted. (also, if that's your actual email address, you might want to edit it out of the question to avoid it being picked up by spammers trawling this site as well!)

Comment: Is there maybe some javascript which empties the title input, before you submit the form?

Comment: this code should have worked, how did you know the subject didn't get through ? is it by checking the mails received ? or is it by dumping its value just before the php function "mail" ?

Comment: It has started to work now.

I echoed out the values. It showed nothing and my emails were showing "No subject"

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP Manual:

> The ('.=') is the concatenating assignment operator, which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side.

In your script, the argument on the left side is empty and it will generate an E_NOTICE saying the `$message` variable is undefined.

In other words, `$message` variable doesn't exist outside your loop, so you're appending to a variable that doesn't exist.

This should fix it:

```
$message = ""; //initialize it
foreach($_POST['form_data'] as $item)
{
//Asigning the message fields to $message variable.
$message .= $item;

...

}
```

Comment: That's a valid suggestion, but it does not address the actual question that was asked.

Comment: But that is working. My problem is, 
$subject = $_POST["email_subject"]; isn't coming though into my script.

Answer (score 1):

The code given is working good and all the values are getting populated in $_POST.
check it and let us know the result

```
array(3) { ["email_address"]=> string(22) "example@googlemail.com" ["email_subject"]=> string(11) "Hello World" ["form_data"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "dwdcw" [1]=> string(2) "fw" [2]=> string(3) "dfw" } }
```

Comment: For some reasons it's decided to work. I think the browser may have cached the page or something. It's very odd!